# How can I package my ruby script using OCRA?

Tags: ocra

My script requires other gem (amatch)to run. Is there a way to still package it using OCRA? I've tried many times, but it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do so, for me this works:

```
ocra myscript.rb --output script.exe --gemfile Gemfile --add-all-core  --gem-full
```